# I am trying to catch a NumberFormatException however the exception is still passing

Tags: java, validation

I have the following example which is meant to catch the fact that `String current = "d"` IS NOT a `double` and it should display a message.

When this code runs, a `NumberFormatException` comes up in the compiler because of the `d`. I believe I have made a really simple error but I just can't see it. Could someone explain where I have gone wrong?

```
public void runAddValidation()
{
    String current = "d";
    double vluRaised = Double.parseDouble(current);

    boolean vTypeDistanceBroke=false;

    try 
    { 
        double vFigure = vluRaised;
        vTypeDistanceBroke=false; 
    }

    catch (NumberFormatException nfe) 
    { 
        vTypeDistanceBroke=true; 
        System.out.println("Type-MoneyRaised: Failed"); 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please add a valid value (No Letters)");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert `parseDouble()` inside `try-catch`

```
public void runAddValidation()
{
    double vluRaised = 0l;
    boolean vTypeDistanceBroke;
    String current = "d";
    double vFigure = vluRaised;

    try 
    { 
        vluRaised = Double.parseDouble(current);

        vTypeDistanceBroke=false; 
    }

    catch (NumberFormatException nfe) 
    { 
        vTypeDistanceBroke=true; 
        System.out.println("Type-MoneyRaised: Failed"); 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please add a valid value (No Letters)");
    }
}
```

As suggested in comments: check [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble-java.lang.String-) for `parseDouble()` where you can read:

> Throws:
>   **NullPointerException** - if the string is null
>   **NumberFormatException** - if the string does not contain a parsable double.

Comment: Yours won't compile either.

Comment: Javadoc link, for clarity about parseDouble: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 3):

Your Try/Catch doesn't cover the source of the exception. The code will choke long before it ever makes it that far. I've also taken the liberty to resolve some compilation errors in your code. What you should have is:

```
   public void runAddValidation() {
        String current = "d";
        boolean vTypeDistanceBroke=false; 

        try{ 
           //This is where you'll have a problem
          double vluRaised = Double.parseDouble(current);
          double vFigure = vluRaised;

        }

        catch (NumberFormatException nfe){ 
               vTypeDistanceBroke=true; 
               System.out.println("Type-MoneyRaised: Failed"); 
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please add a valid value(No Letters)");
       } 
    }
```

Comment: A little patience @JordiCastilla

Comment: Still won't compile, vTypeDistanceBroke must be declared.